# Removing disabled attribute on a fieldset when select option is selected

Tags: jquery

I have two fieldsets. When the select options in the first are selected, I would like the second fieldset to become enabled. But my code does not work ie the second fieldset remains disabled. Please can someone help?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-3">
         <form role="form" class="comments">
           <fieldset>
             <div class="form-group">
              <select class="form-control">
                <option>Comments</option>
                <option class="activate">Comments 1</option>
                <option class="activate">Comments 2</option>
                <option class="activate">Comments 3</option>
              </select>
            </div> <!--/.form-group-->
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div> <!--/.col-xs-6--> 

      <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-3">
       <form role="form">
         <fieldset id="depend" disabled="true">
           <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control">
              <option>is greater than</option>
              <option>greater than 4</option>
              <option>greater than 5</option>
              <option>greater than 6</option>
            </select>
          </div> <!--/.form-group-->
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div> <!--/.col-xs-6-->
```

The jQuery I have used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.comments .activate').each(function() {
    if($(this).is(':selected')) {
      $('#depend').removeAttr("disabled", 'true');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks as though you will only ever make the `<select>` box enabled, and not disable it again, you can attach a `change()` event handler to it. Also, you should use the `prop()` method when changing the disabled property.

If you wanted to make the `<select>` box disabled if the user selects the first choice again, that's easy too. Just find the `:selected` option with the class `.activate`. If this selection has a length of 1, then a valid option has been selected:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.comments .form-control').change(function(){
        var enable = !$(this).find('option:selected.activate').length;
        $('#depend').prop('disabled', enable); 
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/569tfgx8/1/)

Comment: Glad to have helped (:

Answer (score 0):

The very quick fix - `removeAttr` just expects the attribute name you want to remove. Either do `removeAttr('disabled')` or `attr('disabled', false)`.

However, since `.activate` will always be inside a `<select>` you can bind the event to the `<select>` tag. You can also improve the efficiency of your selectors so they run a bit faster:

```
$('.comments').find('select').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).find(':selected').hasClass('activate')) {
        $('#depend').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}).trigger('change'); // run on load
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, i tried this but I need the change function in Georges answer

Comment: Assuming you're using a halfway new version of jQuery (>1.7.2 I think) then `.on` is the recommended way of binding events. `.change` has been deprecated

Comment: Change is deprecated? Thanks Joe.. will amend my code